# Checkbox validation only if this radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to validate if the below radio button is true then at least one of the checkboxes must be selected.

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Print","Home",FormMethod.Post, new{ @class="form", role ="form")
     {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            If you are multiracial, please complete this item by indicating the ethnic/racial group you identify with most or the ethnic/racial group to which you are usually regarded in the community as belonging.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsMultiracial, "Are you Multiracial?", new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMultiracial, "false", new { onclick = "showRacial(this.value)" }) No
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMultiracial, "true", new { onclick = "showRacial(this.value)" }) Yes
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="multiracial" style="display: none;">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="form-group">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ParentRacialGroups.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" name="ParentRacialGroups.Index" value="@i" />
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ParentRacialGroup" name="ParentRacialGroups[@i].ID" value="@Model.ParentRacialGroups[i].ID" checked="@Model.ParentRacialGroups[i].isChecked" data-size="xs" />
                    <label class="cbx-label small" for="check-2g">@Model.ParentRacialGroups[i].name</label>
                    <br />
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Print" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  }
```

Comment: just pass the object 'this' in the showRacial method and inside the method check if(this.checked == true) then this.value

Comment: How will the form validate?

Comment: what are you using for validation?

Comment: I already have the showRacial in my jquery that is not what  I need help with

Comment: you can just use $('form').submit(function(evt) { and in this event check if the radiobutton is selected and the checkbox is checked

Comment: Okay that then do I show the validation through manual text or alerts?

Comment: you can show it in the same way as you're showing the other validations. its your choice.

Comment: Your browser will call the `submit()` function before the form is to be submitted, and you can prevent it from doing so by modifying the event in the usual way.  This is where you'd check the status of the checkbox, and where you'd perform *all* of your validation.  You can also notify the user of a problem in any number of ways.  (For instance, you might have a div that contains a message which is normally hidden.  If all's well, hide that div; if there's an error, show it.  Lots of ways to do it.  (For example, look at how *StackOverflow.com* does it!)

Comment: All you have shown is the view. Show your controller code where you are doing the validation. Are you adding an error to `ModelState`? How and where do you want to display the error?

Comment: @user3758446, mention your model in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this will be useful to you or not, but still you could try this Logic to do your work using JavaScript

[JSFiddle : Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5wmgrevn/1/)

**HTML**

```
1 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chk" />
2 <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="chk" />
3 <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="chk" />
<br><br>
Radio <input type="radio" value="1" />
```

**JS**

```
var radio = $("input[type='radio']");

radio.click(function() {
var $boxes = $('input[name=chk]:checked');
var num = $boxes.length;

 if(num>0)
 {
    alert(num + " " + "Checkbox selected");
 }
 else
 {
     alert("Not a single Checkbox selected");
 }

});
```